# Optionals in For Case statement

Tags: swift, option-type

I have an array of strings that needs to be converted to an array of integers.

```
import Foundation

let strings = ["One", "2", "Three", "4", "Five", "6"]

let integers = strings.map{Int($0)}

// :Using Optional Binding in a FOR Case Statement
for case let val? in integers {
    print("\(val)")
}
```

In the For Case statement above we are doing pattern matching with Optional values in the [Int?] array. My understanding of the concept is that since the array is an optional int array, the values returned will have to be unwrapped before using them, however we are using Optional Binding here in the For Case statement so the value gets unwrapped into the variable "val". But the variable "val" itself seems to be an optional variable which means that the value needs to be unwrapped again in the print statement, but that gives an error: "cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Int'" which means that "val" is not an optional variable.

This is really confusing. Can someone please explain why is the variable "val" not an optional variable when we are using "?" with it !!

Thanks,
Ujjwal

Answer (score 2):

`val?` is the "optional pattern" and a shortcut for `.some(val)`.
It matches an optional expression if that expression is not `nil`,
and then binds `val` to the *unwrapped* value of the matched expression.

From [Optional Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID520):

> An optional pattern matches values wrapped in a `some(Wrapped)` case of an `Optional<Wrapped>` enumeration. Optional patterns consist of an identifier pattern followed immediately by a question mark and appear in the same places as enumeration case patterns.

Therefore `val` is a non-optional `Int`, as you observed.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `for case` you are iterate on a collection conditionally. It will only iterate and process the elements that match the pattern.In case you describe it is `val?` in another words `optional`.